# Java API for speech to text conversion

Tags: java, speech-recognition, voice

For developing an desktop based app, I am looking for *speech to text conversion* third party lib in Java. (open source will be preferred)

Anybody aware of such API which will be flexible and extendable?

Comment: Why open source?  If there were an API that was closed source and free for use (any way you like), would you reject it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a help from [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/). Sphinx-4 is a state-of-the-art speech recognition system written entirely in the JavaTM programming language.

Comment: I already tried Sphinx-4 but there are too much problem in gram file.
I put numbers from  zero to ten, but the Sphinx-4 not catch my number properly